# Large flex item next to 2x2 grid of flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to learn flexbox. This is the layout I want to reproduce:

[image]

Basically one big main box and the rest are small and create a mini grid.

```css
#test {
  display: flex;
}
.item {
  background-color: #444;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 1 1 33%;
}
.item-1 {
  height: 50px;
}
.item-3 {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div class="item item-1">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="item item-2">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="item item-3">
    C
  </div>
  <div class="item item-4">
    D
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a link to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rL7rqp1r/).

Comment: With that `HTML` you need fixed height on container to get that layout.

Comment: You can't do that with that structure, you'll need to wrap the smaller divs in their own container. Plus the structure doesn't match the image.

Comment: So I need to take out "item-1" from the flex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
#test {
  display: flex;
}
#test > div {
  flex: 0 0 48%;                /* width of first flex item in main container */
  height: 120px;
}
section {
  flex: 0 0 48%;                /* width of second flex item in main container */
  display: flex;                /* nested flex container to arrange smaller items */
  flex-wrap: wrap;              /* make container multi-line */
}
section > .item {
  flex: 0 0 40%;                /* width of smaller items; two max per row */
  height: 50px;
}
.item {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <section><!-- NEW; nested flex container -->
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
    <div class="item">D</div>
    <div class="item">E</div>
  </section>
</div>
```